# How to shutdown machine from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, shutdown

I have a machine running Windows Home Server v1 (WHS is based on Windows Server 2003 and is runningh IIS6) and on here I have a restful webservice running which I build in C# VS2008 (dotnet 3.5).  From within the webservice I want to be able to;
1 Check that certain windows services are running;
2 Start certain windows services
3 Stop certain windows services
4 Reboot the machine
5 Shutdown the machine

For 1-3 then I am using impersonation to elevate the ASPNET user to the local administrator (it is only me running this on a local secure network) and then "ServiceController" to control the services.  This works perfectly.

For for 4 & 5 I am having issues and can't get it to work.

If I use System.Diagnostics.Process to call the "shutdown.exe" command with the parameters "/s /f" then the process executes without any errors but does not do anything!  No shutdown, no exception nothing and I can't work out why.  I have tried setting the local admin username & password but it does not help, and the impersonate user call does not help.

My code

```
string shut_args = "/s /f /t 10";
Process process1 = new Process();

process1.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown.exe";
process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
SecureString password = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "mypassword")
     password.AppendChar(c);
process1.StartInfo.Password = password;
process1.StartInfo.Domain = "homeserver";
process1.StartInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = shut_args;

process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;                                

impersonateValidUser();
process1.Start();
```

So instead I tried to use WMI (code taken from another post on here) but here I get an "Privilege not held" error when trying to call InvokeMethod

Mycode

```
ManagementBaseObject mboShutdown = null; ManagementClass mcWin32 = new ManagementClass    ("Win32_OperatingSystem"); mcWin32.Get();        
            mcWin32.Scope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            mcWin32.Scope.Options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Connect;
            mcWin32.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            ManagementBaseObject mboShutdownParams = mcWin32.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown");        

            // Flag 1 means we want to shut down the system. Use "2" to reboot.        
            mboShutdownParams["Flags"] = "1";        
            mboShutdownParams["Reserved"] = "0";        
            foreach (ManagementObject manObj in mcWin32.GetInstances())        
            {
                mboShutdown = manObj.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", mboShutdownParams, null);        
            }
```

I have also been through all of my security settings for the ASPNET and NETWORK_SERVICE user and they have rights to shutdown the server, the WMI security settings are also set-up for these users.  But I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to run a simple batch file instead of starting up the shutdown process in ASP.NET ?
The whole process is described here: [remote shutdown/restart using ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yuanwang200409/RemoteRestartWindows09252006141003PM/RemoteRestartWindows.aspx)

Comment: Wow, calling the bat file works!  But I would consider it more of a workaround than a nice solution, and would appreciate any comments on what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I wanted to do this myself, and just figured out the answer. So try this:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "shutdown";
startInfo.Arguments = "/s /t 5";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```