# Shutdown another System using shutdown.exe in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, remoting, shutdown, system-shutdown

I use the following code for shutdown the own System.It was working Fine.And I need to  **shut down another System, which is connected in LAN Connection**. I'm unable to do it with this code. How to Shutdown another System using shutdown.exe? My OS is windows7.

```
using System.Diagnostics;


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-s -t 00");

        }
```

Comment: also hope you make sure you have admin rights in the other system. next time you want to check for options for a command try the help for the command in command prompt.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I use like this Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-s -t 00 //ComputerName");.It will not work for me..

Comment: Try `\\Computername`, not `//Computername`.

Comment: Check these answers these might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104765/c-sharp-using-shutdown-exe-just-shutdown

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966924/how-to-shutdown-machine-from-asp-net

Comment: @AndrewSklyarevsky I use both //Computername and \\Computername.Both are not working..

Comment: `shutdown /m \\computername`?

Comment: Tried running the same command from console, outside of C#? Maybe it just don't work?

Comment: This is the exact command I used today to do this: `shutdown -m \\au2068serv.local -r` to restart a server located on my desk (with no screen attached). That should work (I'm on Win7).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I do like this way, protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("shutdown -m \\servername.systemName -r");

        }.It causes the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu Start->Run->type cmd-> press enter

in cmd type

```
shutdown /?
```

You can see help, according to help the key you need is

```
   /m \\computer Specify the target computer.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

```
Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-s -t 00 \\computer");
```